# Objective-C project adding a Swift framework, can import bridge header, but it show undeclared swift class

Tags: ios

In `Objective-C` project, I have added a [Swift Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) of [TextFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects) that inherit of [UITextField](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/).  In a `Objective-C` file, I can successfully import `test-Swift.h`,  but it shows the `Swift class` **is undeclared**, I had build the bridge with `Objective-C` and `Swift`. [TextFieldEffects](https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects) declared with `@IBDesignable` public class in `Swift` file:

```
@IBDesignable public class HoshiTextField: TextFieldEffects
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .h file where it's complaining about a Swift class being undeclared, [did you try doing a forward declaration](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com/2014/09/swift-basic-step-by-step-use-of-swift.html)?

That is, something like:

```
@class HoshiTextField;

@interface SomeOtherClass : NSObject

@end
```

Comment: When I add a class declare, it will show the error
    Receiver type 'HoshiTextField' for instance message is a forward declaration
    Receiver HoshiTextField for class message is a forward declaration